# How can I test some Python code which makes use of the requests package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script which uses the `requests` package to make a `get` request to a url to download a (large) file.

Becuase the file is large, I cannot use this in the current state for testing. (It takes about 20 minutes to download.)

Is there a way I can use another Python package to setup a local process/server which can provide a "fake" (or just shorter) version of this file for testing purposes? It doesn't matter if I have to change the url for testing, and indeed I would expect to do so.

Under test conditions, the application can just ask for a localhost address. `localhost:/test_endpoint`, or something.

The code I use to make the request to download the file is just two lines.

```
url = 'http://blaa_blaa.txt'
request = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: Are you wanting to test the actual process of downloading the file?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes - what I imagine is using some kind of Python package which can act as a server on localhost, which can then serve a cut-down version of the actual file. Then the application under test can just point to that localhost address and pull the file from there?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by writing a short application using Flask to act as a fake versin of the actual server the production application would query.

Flask uses port `5000` by default, so the URL needed to be changed to point at the correct host and this port number.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'go to /filename.txt to download file'

@app.route('/filename.txt')
def filename_txt():
    
    with open('filename-test.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    
        data = input_file.read()
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Comment: That's not the best solution. You should remove hard dependency on `requests` from your code instead and abstract that by introducing "middleman", so i.e your code will expect class implementing `Downloader` interface (yes, I know we talk python but that's general principle). So at runtime you will give it `Downloader` which uses `requests` under the hood, but for testing you can give it `Downloader` that does whateevr you want (i.e. load from file, generate data etc, etc)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I understand your point - but this isn't the appropriate solution. I am not trying to test the downstream logic. I am trying to test, quite literally, does the application connect to a remote endpoint every hour and download some data. Trust me when I say I would be the first person to weild the Design Patterns hammer should the situation have given any excuse to use it.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Had I been writing a unit test for some logic block used in the application this would be the correct way to go about it, but that isn't what's happening here.

Comment: Still, technicality aside it still makes little sense for me. `I am trying to test, quite literally, does the application connect to a remote endpoint every hour and download some data` Then you are not testing, but you are monitoring, no? What is your test proven if you do not control the endpoint? That you can deal with the file you serve. That's it. If the real ednpoint hand you garbage you then what? if connection is down then what? For me it looks you should rethink what you want to achieve and you simply asked wrong question.

Comment: I don't understand why people on this site insist on arguing and insisting that they know more about what I'm currently working on than I do, given that they have no idea what I am doing. I've been doing this job for 10 years. Weirdly enough, I know what I am trying to achieve here. @MarcinOrlowski If you check the question you will see that this is exactly what I was asking for.